# Apache Ignite Linq over SQL

Tags: c#, sql, linq, .net-core, ignite

I set up all of my caches using SQL api; I want to use Linq to query over the data in these tables.

How to do this properly?

This is what I have. My model look like this:

```cs
public class Thing
{
    [QuerySqlField]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [QuerySqlField]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [QuerySqlField]
    public DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }
}
```

I defined the table as follow:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Things (
    Id UUID,
    Name VARCHAR,
    EffectiveDate TIMESTAMP,

    PRIMARY KEY(Id))
WITH ""
    TEMPLATE = PARTITIONED,
    CACHE_NAME = consoleappserver.Thing,
    VALUE_TYPE = consoleappserver.Thing""
```

Now I am attempting a linq over that

```cs
var cache = cli.GetCache<Guid, Thing>(typeof(Thing).FullName);
var things = cache.AsCacheQueryable();
var effectiveDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Today, DateTimeKind.Utc);
things = things.Where(t => t.Value.EffectiveDate <= effectiveDate);

foreach (var kv in things)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Things #{0} '{1}'",
        kv.Value.Id, kv.Value.Name);
}
```

I get the following error because the sql looks like this:

```
'Failed to parse query. Column "_T0.EffectiveDate" not found; SQL statement:
select _T0._KEY, _T0._VAL from "PUBLIC"."THINGS" as _T0 
where (_T0."EffectiveDate" <= ?) [42122-199]'
```

Comment: It seems to be working fine for me. What's your concern? Try something more complex like cli.GetCache<Guid, Thing>(typeof(Thing).FullName).Where(f => filter(f)).Select(record => record.Value.Field)

Comment: I updated the question to include the whole scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem: Ignite converts column names to uppercase, but LINQ provider uses quoted identifiers, so the requested column name `EffectiveDate` does not match actual `EFFECTIVEDATE`.

**Solution 1**

Use quoted identifiers in the DDL query so that column name case is preserved:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Things (
    "Id" UUID,
    "Name" VARCHAR,
    "EffectiveDate" TIMESTAMP,

    PRIMARY KEY("Id"))
WITH ""
    TEMPLATE = PARTITIONED,
    CACHE_NAME = consoleappserver.Thing,
    VALUE_TYPE = consoleappserver.Thing""
```

**Solution 2**

Specify uppercase column names in the model class:

```
public class Thing
{
    [QuerySqlField(Name = "ID")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [QuerySqlField(Name = "NAME")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [QuerySqlField(Name = "EFFECTIVEDATE")]
    public DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I got past that issue but ran into another one 'Failed to resolve Java class 'consoleappserver.Thing' in .NET [platformId=1, typeId=298456301].'

Comment: @herme0 please provide the details in a separate question

Comment: I created a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69393993/apache-ignite-linq-over-sql-faile-to-resolve-java-class)