# Apache Ignite Linq over Sql Failed to resolve java class

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, ignite

I am doing linq over tables I created using sql api.

I created the table:

```
var cfg = new CacheClientConfiguration(
    "PUBLIC",
    new QueryEntity(typeof(object), typeof(object)))
    {
        SqlSchema = "PUBLIC",
        CacheMode = CacheMode.Partitioned
    };

var cache = cli.GetOrCreateCache<object, object>(cfg);
cache.Query(new SqlFieldsQuery(@"
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Things 
    (
        Id UUID,
        Name VARCHAR,
        EffectiveDate TIMESTAMP,

        PRIMARY KEY(Id)
    )
    WITH ""TEMPLATE = PARTITIONED,
           CACHE_NAME = consoleappserver.Thing,
           VALUE_TYPE = consoleappserver.Thing""
")).GetAll();
```

I put some seed data:

```
cache.Query(new SqlFieldsQuery(@"
    INSERT INTO Things (Id, Name, EffectiveDate) VALUES (?,?,?)",
    Guid.NewGuid(), "Test Name 1", DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Today, DateTimeKind.Utc))).GetAll();

cache.Query(new SqlFieldsQuery(@"
    INSERT INTO Things (Id, Name, EffectiveDate) VALUES (?,?,?)",
    Guid.NewGuid(), "Test Name 2", DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Today.AddDays(1), DateTimeKind.Utc))).GetAll();

cache.Query(new SqlFieldsQuery(@"
    INSERT INTO Things (Id, Name, EffectiveDate) VALUES (?,?,?)",
    Guid.NewGuid(), "Test Name 3", DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Today.AddDays(2), DateTimeKind.Utc))).GetAll();
```

Here is my linq query:

```
var cache = cli.GetCache<Guid, Thing>("consoleappserver.Thing");
var things = cache.AsCacheQueryable();
var effectiveDate = DateTime.SpecifyKind(DateTime.Today, DateTimeKind.Utc);
things = things.Where(t => t.Value.EffectiveDate <= effectiveDate);

foreach (var kv in things)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Things #{0} '{1}'", kv.Value.Id, kv.Value.Name);
}
```

Here is the C# class I use for mapping:

```
public class Thing
{
    [QuerySqlField(Name = "ID")]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [QuerySqlField(Name = "NAME")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [QuerySqlField(Name = "EFFECTIVEDATE")]
    public DateTime EffectiveDate { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the error I get when I try to iterate over **things**:

> Apache.Ignite.Core.Client.IgniteClientException:
> 'Failed to resolve Java class 'consoleappserver.Thing' in .NET [platformId=1, typeId=298456301].'

Here is the full error logged:

> [11:00:18,731][SEVERE][client-connector-#110][ClientListenerNioListener] Failed to process client request [req=o.a.i.i.processors.platform.client.binary.ClientBinaryTypeNameGetRequest@250d2f65]
> class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Failed to resolve Java class 'consoleappserver.Thing' in .NET [platformId=1, typeId=298456301].
> at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.client.binary.ClientBinaryTypeNameGetRequest.process(ClientBinaryTypeNameGetRequest.java:57)
> at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.client.ClientRequestHandler.handle(ClientRequestHandler.java:93)
> at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.ClientListenerNioListener.onMessage(ClientListenerNioListener.java:202)
> at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.ClientListenerNioListener.onMessage(ClientListenerNioListener.java:58)
> at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterChain$TailFilter.onMessageReceived(GridNioFilterChain.java:278)
> at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterAdapter.proceedMessageReceived(GridNioFilterAdapter.java:108)
> at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioAsyncNotifyFilter$3.body(GridNioAsyncNotifyFilter.java:135)
> at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:119)
> at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorkerPool$1.run(GridWorkerPool.java:69)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to resolve Java class 'consoleappserver.Thing' in .NET [platformId=1, typeId=298456301].
> at org.apache.ignite.internal.MarshallerContextImpl.getClassName(MarshallerContextImpl.java:400)
> at org.apache.ignite.internal.MarshallerContextImpl.getClassName(MarshallerContextImpl.java:333)
> at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.platform.client.binary.ClientBinaryTypeNameGetRequest.process(ClientBinaryTypeNameGetRequest.java:52)
> ... 11 more

Comment: Can you please check server node logs and attach the full error details from there? The log should contain the same exception message "Failed to resolve..." but with a server-side stack trace.

Comment: I have added that

Comment: How do you insert data into cache? With SQL or from Java?

Comment: The sample data were inserted using sql (api)

Comment: Thanks for the additional details, I can reproduce it. Which Ignite version are you on?

Comment: I am using the community version 8.8.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the table is defined with SQL, `Thing` type is not known to Ignite. Use the following call before the query to force binary type registration:

```
cli.GetBinary().GetBinaryType(typeof(Thing));
```

This call can be done once per client instance after `Ignition.StartClient`.

Comment: why is the primary key field(s) not set on the data returned by linq?

Comment: @herme0 key columns get mapped to the cache key, this prints the key: `Console.WriteLine("Things #{0} '{1}'", kv.Key, kv.Value.Name)`