# When I try to using Apache Ignite Linq It gives a .Net Resolving error

Tags: .net, ignite

I have a Web API based on .NET 6.
I'm using Apache Ignite as the distributed cache system. It runs on Azure Kubernetes Service.

It works well, but When I try to use Apache Ignite Linq I am getting following error.

> Failed to resolve .NET class apache ignite

Here is my class and initializing part of my code,

```
public class Product
    {
        public string ItemId {  get; set; }
        public string ItemDesc { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public string ArticleCode { get; set; }
        public string Barcode { get; set; }
        [QuerySqlField]
        public string ColorId { get; set; }
        public string ColorDesc { get; set; }
        [QuerySqlField]
        public string SizeId { get; set; }
}


public void ConnectIgnite()
        {
            _ignite = Ignition.StartClient(GetIgniteConfiguration());
        }

        public IgniteClientConfiguration GetIgniteConfiguration()
        {
            var appSettingsJson = AppSettingsJson.GetAppSettings();

            var igniteEndpoints = appSettingsJson["AppSettings:IgniteEndpoint"];
            var igniteUser = appSettingsJson["AppSettings:IgniteUser"];
            var ignitePassword = appSettingsJson["AppSettings:IgnitePassword"];
            var nodeList = igniteEndpoints.Split(",");

            var config = new IgniteClientConfiguration
            {
                Endpoints = nodeList,
                UserName = igniteUser,
                Password = ignitePassword,
                EnablePartitionAwareness = true
            };

            return config;
        }

        private void InitializeCaches()
        {
            //_organizationCache = CreateCache<string, Organization>("PUBLIC", typeof(Organization));
            _testCache = CreateCache<string, List<string>>(CacheConstants.TEST_CACHE, new QueryEntity(typeof(string), typeof(string)));
            _userCache = CreateCache<string, User>(CacheConstants.USER_CACHE, new QueryEntity(typeof(string), typeof(User)));
            _deviceCache = CreateCache<string, Device>(CacheConstants.DEVICE_CACHE, new QueryEntity(typeof(string), typeof(Device)));
            _productCache = CreateCache<string, Product>(CacheConstants.PRODUCT_CACHE, new QueryEntity(typeof(string), typeof(Product)));
        }

        private ICacheClient<TK, TV> CreateCache<TK, TV>(string name, QueryEntity queryEntity)
        {
            var config = GetCacheConfiguration(name, queryEntity);
            return _ignite.GetOrCreateCache<TK, TV>(config);
        }

private static CacheClientConfiguration GetCacheConfiguration(string name, QueryEntity queryEntity)
        {
            var config = new CacheClientConfiguration(name, queryEntity);
            config.CacheMode = CacheMode.Replicated;
            config.RebalanceMode = CacheRebalanceMode.Async;
            return config;
        }
```

And here is my code calling linq

```
public List<Product> SearchProduct(string colorId, string sizeId, string departmantId)
{
    IQueryable<ICacheEntry<string, Product>> queryable = _cacheManager.ProductCache.AsCacheQueryable();
    Product[] list = (Product[])queryable.Where(x => x.Value.ColorId.Equals(colorId) && x.Value.SizeId.Equals(sizeId)).ToArray();

    return list.ToList();
}
```

The Error :

[image]

Comment: Try `_ignite.GetBinary().GetBinaryType(typeof(AllStore.Model.General.User))` before the query to force binary type registration in Ignite.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69393993/apache-ignite-linq-over-sql-failed-to-resolve-java-class/69422851