# Failed to resolve .NET class 'System.DateTime' - apache ignite with .Net

Tags: ignite, gridgain

Apache ignite throwing System.DateTime exception when executing the SqlFieldsQuery for Datetime column but same time ignite saves the data successfully.
The entities are created via configuration file as below

```
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                <property name="name" value="TEST"/>
                <property name="cacheMode" value="PARTITIONED"/>
                <property name="atomicityMode" value="TRANSACTIONAL"/>
                <property name="writeSynchronizationMode" value="FULL_SYNC"/>

                <!-- Configure type metadata to enable queries. -->
                <property name="queryEntities">
                    <list>
                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.QueryEntity">

                            <property name="keyType" value="java.lang.Long"/>
                            <property name="valueType" value="TEST"/>

                            <property name="fields">
                                <map>
                                    <entry key="ID" value="java.lang.Long"/>
                                    <entry key="DATE" value="java.sql.Timestamp"/>                                      
                                </map>
                            </property>
                        </bean>
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
```

here is the C# code to upload the values and reading...

```
 string cacheName = "TEST";
            try
            {
                using (IIgnite ignite = Ignition.Start("RemoteDevServer.config"))
                {
//ignite.GetBinary().GetBinaryType(cacheName);


var cache = ignite.GetCache<long, IBinaryObject>(cacheName).WithKeepBinary<long, IBinaryObject>();
                    var objectBuilder = ignite.GetBinary().GetBuilder(cacheName);
                    long Id = 100;
                    objectBuilder.SetField("ID", Id);
                    objectBuilder.SetField("DATE", DateTime.Now);
                    cache[Id] = objectBuilder.Build();

                    var sqlp = new SqlFieldsQuery("select ID, DATE from TEST ");
                    using (var cursor = cache.Query(sqlp))
                    {
                        foreach (var row in cursor) // throws exception 
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(row[0] + "---" + row[1]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
```

Here is the error details

```
 Failed to execute map query on remote node [nodeId=fa1cb87b-7a6a-46f0-aa21-0e1f680f241e, errMsg=General error: "class org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryInvalidTypeException: Failed to resolve .NET class 'System.DateTime' in Java [platformId=0, typeId=-1854586790]."; SQL statement:
SELECT
"__Z0"."ID" AS "__C0_0",
"__Z0"."DATE" AS "__C0_1"
FROM "TEST"."TEST" AS "__Z0" [50000-199]]
```

I tried a solution recommended here - [Apache Ignite Linq over Sql Failed to resolve java class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69393993/apache-ignite-linq-over-sql-failed-to-resolve-java-class)  but didn't resolve the issue. According to the link here - https://www.gridgain.com/docs/latest/sql-reference/data-types  java.sql.Timestamp should match with System.DateTime but unfortunately not.
any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `objectBuilder.SetField("DATE", DateTime.Now);` with `objectBuilder.SetTimestampField("DATE", DateTime.UtcNow);`.

- Only UTC values are supported in SQL.
- When using `IBinaryObjectBuilder`, call `SetTimestampField` instead `SetField`.

I would also recommend to enable `ForceTimestamp` mode to catch those issues early:

```
var igniteCfg = new IgniteConfiguration
{
  BinaryConfiguration = new BinaryConfiguration
  {
    ForceTimestamp = true
  }
}
```

Comment: Absolutly perfect. Many thanks @Pavel. is it possible to put ForceTimestamp = true in the config? I tried as below but didn't success. <property name="binaryConfiguration">
   <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.BinaryConfiguration">
       <property name="ForceTimestamp" value="true"/>   
   </bean>
  </property>

Comment: @JustinMathew this is a .NET configuration property, and should be set in C# code or in `RemoteDevServer.config`